# How to highlight the bullet points one by one?

Tags: beamer, highlighting, emphasis, bullets

I would like to achieve the following effect:

1. Show the first bullet point and highlight the keywords in it;
2. Show both the first and the second bullet points and highlight the keywords in the second bullet point;
3. Show the first, second, third bullet points and highlight the keywords in the third bullet point.

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Issues}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> First issue: {\color{red} blabla} 
\item<2-> First issue: blabla
\item<2> Second issue: {\color{red}blabla}
\item<3-> Second issue: blabla
\item<3> Third issue: {\color{red} blabla}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

But the distance between the title and the first bullet point changes across slides, and there is a weird gap between the first and the second bullet point. How can I fix this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Your first (third) bullet point is shown only on slide one (two). However it occupies the space also on the following slides.

Instead of hiding the entire bullet point and rewriting it, you could use the `\temporal` macro to temporarily colorize the text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\colorize<#1>{%
    \temporal<#1>{}{\color{red}}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Issues}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> First issue:  {\colorize<1>blabla} 
        \item<2-> Second issue: {\colorize<2>blabla}
        \item<3-> Third issue:  {\colorize<3>blabla}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]